# django ajax: User matching query does not exist

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

So I made a django ajax that everytime there is a new message the notification object that I add to my user models will be +1, the problem is that I dont know why is giving me this error:

```
django.contrib.auth.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
```

here is my code:

views.py:

```
def count_notification(request): 
    user = request.user  
    obj = user.profile.objects.get(pk=1)
    obj.notifications = obj.notifications +1
    obj.save()
    response_data = {'success':1}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

urls.py:

```
path('messages/notification/', count_notification)
```

html file js

```
// Add the notification val
$.get('notification/')
```

models.py:

```
class ProfileImage(models.Model):
    """
    Profile model
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        verbose_name=_('User'),
        to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='profile',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image')
    notifications = models.FloatField(default='0')
```

thank you for the help

Comment: it is telling you that the user does not exist, so in this case a `User` instance with `id` equal to `1` does not exists, so the query fails.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf So how can I fixed it, I want to change to the notification value of the user that is logged

Answer (score 0):

```
obj = user.profile.objects.get(pk=1)
```

i think your app is dealing with many users, each user has its own profile with its own notification count, so why you are fixing the id / pk to 1, you need to get the related profile, not hard code the id

try this code below

```
def count_notification(request):
    user = request.user

    user.profile.notifications += 1
    user.profile.save()

    response_data = {'success':1}

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

and change

```
notifications = models.FloatField(default='0')
```

to

```
notifications = models.IntegerField(default='0')
```

it does make more sens since notifications count is an integer not float nand don't forget to rerun migrations

## Update

i guess you have not defined a custom `User` model in `settings.py` in this case you need to make some changes in `models.py`

refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#reusable-apps-and-auth-user-model

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model  # get the default User model

User = get_user_model()

class ProfileImage(models.Model):
    """
    Profile model
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        verbose_name=_('User'),
        # to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, # you don't need this since you didn't 
                                       # defined a custom User model in 
                                       # setting.py
        to = User,  # HERE
        related_name='profile',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image')
    notifications = models.IntegerField(default='0')  # change the field type
```

## Update 2

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

..

def count_notification(request):
    # user = request.user
    user = User.objects.filter(id=request.user.id).first()  # HERE

    user.profile.notifications += 1
    user.profile.save()

    response_data = {'success':1}

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: in `settings.py` please check first `AUTH_USER_MODEL` you to mention your custom `User` model

Comment: I dont have an auth_user_model in my settings

Comment: and I also makemigrations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219629/discussion-between-bernardo-olisan-and-cizario).